# Replicating excel YIELD results using Strata for bonds in JAVA

Tags: java, excel, finance, quantitative-finance

In calculating a bond's yield, I am trying to replicate the results calculated using excel's YIELD function using the Strata package developed by OpenGamma. However, comparing the figures calculated using excel and strata, I notice that there is a small discrepancy which grows when the duration of the bond is longer.

This is an example of my calculation in excel:
[Excel Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeciH.png)

The calculated results is 6.5%

When i do the same calcuation in Strata as such:

```
    DiscountingFixedCouponBondPaymentPeriodPricer paymentPeriodPricer = new DiscountingFixedCouponBondPaymentPeriodPricer();
    DiscountingPaymentPricer discountingPaymentPricer = new DiscountingPaymentPricer();
    DiscountingFixedCouponBondProductPricer pricer = new DiscountingFixedCouponBondProductPricer(paymentPeriodPricer,discountingPaymentPricer);

    LocalDate settlementDate = LocalDate.of(2008, 2, 15);
    LocalDate maturityDate = LocalDate.of(2016,11,15);
    double couponRate = 0.0575;
    double dirtyPrice=0.9504287;

    com.opengamma.strata.basics.currency.Currency bondcurrency = com.opengamma.strata.basics.currency.Currency.of("USD");
    BusinessDayAdjustment businessDayAdj =
            BusinessDayAdjustment.of(BusinessDayConventions.FOLLOWING, HolidayCalendarIds.USNY );
    PeriodicSchedule definition = PeriodicSchedule.builder()
            .startDate(settlementDate)
            .endDate(maturityDate)
            .businessDayAdjustment(businessDayAdj)
            .frequency(Frequency.P6M)
            .stubConvention(StubConvention.SHORT_INITIAL)
            .rollConvention(RollConventions.EOM)
            .build();
    FixedCouponBond bond = FixedCouponBond.builder()
            .currency(bondcurrency)
            .notional(1)
            .fixedRate(couponRate)
            .accrualSchedule(definition)
            .securityId(SecurityId.of("WHATISTHIS","FOR"))
            .dayCount(DayCounts.THIRTY_360_ISDA)
            .yieldConvention(FixedCouponBondYieldConvention.JP_SIMPLE)
            .legalEntityId(StandardId.of("WHATISTHIS","FOR"))
            .settlementDateOffset(DaysAdjustment.ofBusinessDays(2,HolidayCalendarIds.SAT_SUN))
            .build();

    double yieldOfBond = pricer.yieldFromDirtyPrice(bond.resolve(ReferenceData.standard()),settlementDate,dirtyPrice);
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(yieldOfBond*100));
```

The yield figure printed is 6.645978959660144%.

May I know if I might have configured any of the parameters wrongly as the strata yield function takes in a few other parameters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be starting with a clean price? try this:

```
DiscountingFixedCouponBondProductPricer pricer =
        DiscountingFixedCouponBondProductPricer.DEFAULT;
LocalDate settlementDate = LocalDate.of(2008, 2, 15);
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2007, 11, 15);
LocalDate maturityDate = LocalDate.of(2016, 11, 15);
double couponRate = 0.0575;
double cleanPrice = 0.9504287;

Currency bondcurrency = Currency.USD;
BusinessDayAdjustment businessDayAdj = BusinessDayAdjustment.of(
        BusinessDayConventions.FOLLOWING, HolidayCalendarIds.USNY);
PeriodicSchedule definition = PeriodicSchedule.builder()
    .startDate(startDate)
    .endDate(maturityDate)
    .businessDayAdjustment(businessDayAdj)
    .frequency(Frequency.P6M)
    .stubConvention(StubConvention.SHORT_INITIAL)
    .rollConvention(RollConventions.DAY_15)
    .build();
FixedCouponBond bond = FixedCouponBond.builder()
    .currency(bondcurrency)
    .notional(1)
    .fixedRate(couponRate)
    .accrualSchedule(definition)
    .securityId(SecurityId.of("WHATISTHIS", "FOR"))
    .dayCount(DayCounts.THIRTY_360_ISDA)
    .yieldConvention(FixedCouponBondYieldConvention.US_STREET)
    .legalEntityId(StandardId.of("WHATISTHIS", "FOR"))
    .settlementDateOffset(DaysAdjustment.ofBusinessDays(2, HolidayCalendarIds.USNY))
    .build();

double dirtyPrice = pricer.dirtyPriceFromCleanPrice(bond.resolve(ReferenceData.standard()), settlementDate, cleanPrice);
double yield = pricer.yieldFromDirtyPrice(bond.resolve(ReferenceData.standard()), settlementDate, dirtyPrice);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(yield * 100d));
```

The `securityId` and `legalEntityId` are used when interacting with stores or reference and market data.